# How to save a PDF file in a SQL Server column using vb.net code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How to save a PDF file in a SQL Server column using vb.net code,by memory stream ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you must have column of type varbinary(MAX) in your table in database. It allows you to save bytes array in it.

Next you can use such line of code to get contents of your PDF file as byte array:

```
IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\my.pdf")
```

Comment: `ntext , text, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.`[(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Then use varbinary(MAX). But specify MAX, not some number, since MAX allows usage of up to 2^31-1 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

thank you!!!
my solution now is :

```
public void SaveFile()
{
    //Try
    OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
    fd.Filter = "pdf file|*.pdf";
    if (fd.ShowDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
        //PdfDocument1.FilePath = fd.FileName


        byte[] filebyte = null;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALHOS-A4AE79\\LOCALHOST1;Initial Catalog=library_alborz;Integrated Security=True");


        SqlCommand cmd = default(SqlCommand);

        filebyte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fd.FileName);


        cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into pdftbl ( pdffld ) Values(@pdf)", con);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@filepath", SqlType.VarChar).Value = txtfilepath.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdf", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = filebyte;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Interaction.MsgBox("File saved into database", MsgBoxStyle.Information);
        //Catch ex As Exception
        //    MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        //End Try

    }
}


------------
// load pdf file

private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string strsql = null;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALHOS-A4AE79\\LOCALHOST1;Initial Catalog=library_alborz;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try {
        strsql = "select pdffld from  pdftbl ";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, con);
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl");

        //Get image data from gridview column.
        byte[] pdfData = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables["tbl"].Rows[0][0]);

        //Initialize pdf  variable

        //Read pdf  data into a memory stream
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfData, 0, pdfData.Length)) {
            ms.Write(pdfData, 0, pdfData.Length);

            //Set pdf variable value using memory stream.
            PdfDocument1.Load(ms);
            PdfPageView1.Document = PdfDocument1;
            PdfPageView1.Refresh();

        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```