# How to Convert PDF file to SQL Server Image data type

Tags: c#, sql-server

Using C# How do i convert a PDF file to store in SQL as SQL Server Image data type?

Following is my sql, I want to store PDF as template to TemplateFile column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Templates](
    [TemplateID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TemplateFile] [image] NOT NULL,
    [LanguageId] [bigint] NOT NULL)
```

I want to preferably store the PDF as a Hex string in SQL Image column

sample output required...0x255044462D312E360D25E2E3CFD30D0A36353

Comment: Are you aware that the image data type will soon be deprecated? you should be using varbinary(MAX)

Comment: @asemprini87 No I was't aware of it, Thank you for the heads up, however, as the db already exists I would like to keep it like that for now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10310197/1384539

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is a deep misconception how SQL-Server stores such data...

**Binary data is not stored as HEX string!** This is just the way it is presented to you when you see the result of a `SELECT MyBinaryColumn FROM SomeWhere`.

Binary data is not understandable for a human reader. It must be formatted to a readable string.

This applies to other data types too, which store their values in a binary format internally: In many cases **the values you *see* are not the real values**. This is especially painfull in connection with datetime values, where the presented string depends on system and culture settings. The same thing leads to silly errors, if floating point numbers are presented with an implicit rounding (*Oh! 13.00000001 is not equal to 13...*).

Today one should store binary data in a column of data type `VARBINARY(MAX)`. The `IMAGE` data type (same with `TEXT`) is deprecated and will not be supported anymore in future versions!

You can pass your value as a byte array (`byte[]`) from C# as `SqlDbType.Binary`. Thiago Custodio pointed in his comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310197/5089204) showing an example.